# mySQL AVG - A way to merge two results for AVG

Tags: php, mysql, average

I'm trying to get the average number of interactions on my metrics, but this query gets the average number of inteactions for those who DID interact (those in metricsActions are only there if they HAVE interacted, their metricsID still exists in `metrics` table).

So, I'm wondering how I can get the average of all those users. I can do two queries, but then how would I average with the two results? Is it possible to merge?

```
SELECT AVG(`instances`) FROM (SELECT m.`metricID`, COUNT(mc.`metricAction`) as `instances` FROM `metricActions` mc LEFT JOIN `metrics` m ON m.`metricID` = mc.`metricID` WHERE m.`clientID` = '10412' AND `type` = '2' AND GROUP BY mc.`metricID` ORDER BY `instances` DESC ) as `temp`
```

Comment: Could you please post the tables structure?

Comment: Any link examples on what formatting of structure you want so I don't spam?

Comment: Copy the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` (for each table) and paste it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `LEFT JOIN` the other way around:

```
SELECT  AVG(`instances`)
FROM    (
        SELECT  m.`metricID`, COUNT(mc.`metricAction`) as `instances`
        FROM   `metrics` m
        LEFT JOIN
                `metricActions` mc
        ON      mc.`metricID` = m.`metricID`
                AND mc.`type` = '2'
        WHERE   m.`clientID` = '10412'
        GROUP BY
                m.`metricID`
        ) as `temp`
```

Comment: That provides the same result. The issue is that metricsActions ONLY has an entry (of which there may be multiple entries/rows) if there has been activity, whilst the user who has 0 entries, but still exists in metrics hasn't been included in the query.

Comment: maybe move up `type = 2` with the join condition?

Comment: @Ronnis: this depends on which table does it belong to. I suppose it's from `metric` and the @op wants to filter on it.

Comment: yeah we don't know since he didn't use aliases. His comment that it returned the "same result" made me think that the column might come from metricActions instead. In that case the filter on TYPE would turn the join into an inner one.

Comment: @Ronnis: seems you may be right. For some reason I just missed the @op's comment entirely.